# Duplicate column name error sqlite3 Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I wanted to create a row with certain attributes:

```
querycurs.execute("CREATE TABLE CME_Equities(Contract Size TEXT, Contract Months TEXT")
```

However, I get an error with the names since they both start with "Contract", is there a way to force it to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your column names contain whitespace you need to put quotes around the names; you are also missing a closing parenthesis:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CME_Equities('Contract Size' TEXT, 'Contract Months' TEXT)
```

Quick demo with the `sqlite3` command line utility:

```
$ sqlite3 :memory:
SQLite version 3.7.16.1 2013-03-29 13:44:34
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> CREATE TABLE CME_Equities('Contract Size' TEXT, 'Contract Months' TEXT);
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE CME_Equities('Contract Size' TEXT, 'Contract Months' TEXT);
```

or the python version:

```python
querycurs.execute("CREATE TABLE CME_Equities('Contract Size' TEXT, 'Contract Months' TEXT)")
```

Comment: I was following a tutorial online and they inserted into tables like this: `cur.execute("INSERT INTO Friends(Name) VALUES ('Tom');")`, however, when I try a similar approach: `querycurs.execute("INSERT INTO CME_Equities(elem) VALUES (cell_in_table);")`, I get an error: `OperationalError: no such column: cell_in_table`. I thought the column is next to the `name of table` and values right after `VALUES`

Comment: You'll need to follow some more SQL tutorials; when inserting a value, you can not only insert literal values, but also data from other SQL expressions. `cell_in_table` is seen as an expression, not a value, because you didn't use quotes.

Comment: The Python equivalent would be to use `foobar = somevalue` instead of `foobar = 'somevalue'`; in the first example `somevalue` would be interpreted as the name of another object, but `'somevalue'` is a string literal.